# Facebook share functionality in wordpress loop

Tags: facebook

I am trying to add `facebook share` functionality to my `wordpress` posts. in my `wp loop` i have a share button

```
<a class="action_button"  href="javascript:void(0)" id="share_button" target="_blank"> share this</a>
```

i am not getting `post title ,post thumpnail` etc. what is wrong with my code.

and before starting loop i have javascript code like

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({appId: 'myappid', status: false, cookie: false, xfbml: false});
  };

  (function() {
     var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
     e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
     document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#share_button').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: '  <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>',
link: ' <?php echo get_permalink(); ?>',
picture: '<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail();?>',
caption: 'This is the content of the "caption" field.',
description: 'This is the content of the "description" field, below the caption.',
message: ''
});
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript is outside the loop, so php can never access `get_the_title()`, `get_permalink()` and `get_the_post_thumbnail()` from there.

What I'd do is include those somewhere in the loop, for instance:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <a class="share-button" data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a>
</div>
```

Then with jQuery, you can grab them from the HTML generated by the loop. For instance the following (and do the same for link and picture):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#share_button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var postTitle = $(this).data( "title" ); // Here's where you grab the title
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            name: postTitle,
            link: ' <?php echo get_permalink(); ?>',
            picture: '<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail();?>',
            caption: 'This is the content of the "caption" field.',
            description: 'This is the content of the "description" field, below the caption.',
            message: ''
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing **single quotes** from your code like this:

```
name: '  <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>',
link: ' <?php echo get_permalink(); ?>',
picture: '<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail();?>',
```

Replace With

```
name:    <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>,
link:    <?php echo get_permalink(); ?>,
picture: <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail();?>,
```